# Is it bad practice to put sections of main code in functions?

Tags: shell-script

I didn't like the way the code that I had looked, so I compressed all of the main 'blocks' into functions. (This would also prevent the code from running if an error was present.) I don't know if this is bad practice or not. Here's the code (about the first line: `bash-4.3` is installed in `/usr/local/bin/bash`.):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
cat /dev/null > out.txt
resetcolor() {
    echo -ne "\e[0m"
}
color() {
    resetcolor
    if [ $# -eq 1 ]
    then
        echo -ne "\033[38;5;${1}m"
        elif  [ $2 == "b" ]
        then
            echo -ne "\033[1;38;5;${1}m"
    fi
}

prob() {
    x=$(echo "scale=4;($1/$c)" | bc)
    y=$(echo "scale=2;$x*100" | bc) 
    if   [[ ${y%??} == *".00"* ]] ; then echo "${y%?????}%"
    elif [[ ${y#????} == "000" ]] ; then echo "${y%????}%"
        elif [[ ${y#???} == "3300" ]] ; then echo "${y%?????}.33%"
    elif [[ ${y#???} == "6600" ]] ; then echo "${y%?????}.67%"
    else echo "${y%??}%"
        fi

}
readmessage() {
if [ $# -eq 1 ]
then
    c=$1
    echo "Flipping coins..."
    else
    echo "Enter number of coins to flip..."
    read c
    echo "Flipping coins..."
fi
}
flip() {
     < /dev/urandom LC_CTYPE=C gtr -dc HT | head -c $c | while read -n 1 ccoin
    do
        echo -n "$ccoin"
        echo "$ccoin" >> out.txt
    done
    echo -e "\n"
}
stats() {
if (($c<10)) 
then
    exit 1
else
    co=$( < out.txt )
    color 035
    echo "Heads:"
        h=`grep -o "H" <<<"$co" | wc -l`
        color 047 b
        echo $h
        resetcolor
        color 027 
    echo "Tails:"
        color 045 b
        t=`grep -o "T" <<<"$co" | wc -l`
        echo $t
        color 255 b
    echo " "
    echo "Experimental probability"     
        echo "Heads:"
            prob $h 
        echo "Tails:"
            prob $t
fi
}
###
readmessage $1
flip
stats
###
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Code Review...

Comment: @jasonwryan Oops, sorry, didn't know I should put it there _(nor did I even know it was a thing, haha!)_

Comment: What's the point of this? It's a coin flip? I think your code could be condensed to `flip(){ return "$(tr -c 01 '[0*127][1*]|dd bs=1)"; } </dev/urandom`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely **not** a bad practice. Using functions is one of the good ways to divide code into blocks. This way it's easy to:

- see what parts of code are enabled
- disable a part of code
- see what parts of code are doing what, because they are labeled and clearly parted from other parts of code with functions